# How to convert the dates to range of dates?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am currently working on data extract from Kronos Leave Module. The data is about Employee, which dates he took leaves what is the reason and status. So the dates are where the challenge is as I need to convert the dates to a range of dates instead day by day which is currently been pulled.

Current File:

```
Absence_ID  |Person_num  |Work_type   |Leave_type  |Segement_Start_Date  |Segement_End_Date   |Status
------------|------------|------------|------------|---------------------|--------------------|-----------------------
11617       |200146      |C           |VERMOUNT    |01/28/2019 0:00      |01/28/2019 0:00     |Closed-Returned to Work
11617       |200146      |C           |VERMOUNT    |01/29/2019 0:00      |01/29/2019 0:00     |Closed-Returned to Work
11617       |200146      |C           |VERMOUNT    |01/30/2019 0:00      |01/30/2019 0:00     |Closed-Returned to Work
11617       |200146      |C           |VERMOUNT    |01/31/2019 0:00      |01/31/2019 0:00     |Closed-Returned to Work
11617       |200146      |C           |VERMOUNT    |02/01/2019 0:00      |02/01/2019 0:00     |Closed-Returned to Work
11617       |200146      |C           |VERMOUNT    |02/04/2019 0:00      |02/04/2019 0:00     |Closed-Returned to Work
11617       |200146      |C           |VERMOUNT    |02/05/2019 0:00      |02/05/2019 0:00     |Closed-Returned to Work
11617       |200146      |C           |VERMOUNT    |02/06/2019 0:00      |02/06/2019 0:00     |Closed-Returned to Work
11617       |200146      |C           |VERMOUNT    |02/07/2019 0:00      |02/07/2019 0:00     |Closed-Returned to Work
11617       |200146      |C           |VERMOUNT    |02/08/2019 0:00      |02/08/2019 0:00     |Closed-Returned to Work
```

Corrected:

```
Absence_ID  |Work_type   |Leave_type  |Segement_Start_Date |Segement_End_Date   |Status  
------------|------------|------------|--------------------|--------------------|--------
11617       |C           |VT-FML      |01/28/2019          |02/08/2019          |Approved
```

Comment: Have a look for "gaps and islands" or "contiguous dates to range" - this kind of question is asked quite frequently. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24289958/find-start-and-stop-date-for-contiguous-dates-in-multiple-rows , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27471514/group-continuous-date-ranges-from-same-table-sql-server , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20402089/detect-consecutive-dates-ranges-using-sql For example

Comment: I think you forgot to ask a question here, along with explain your goals and show your attempts. I can't see how that data related at all (especially as they have different values for `Status`).

Comment: My first guess would be a group by Absence_ID, work type, leave type, selecting min start date and max end date. But I bet there are more important details that you did no mention. For example, when is the status "approved"?

Comment: @heringer your idea worked for me with min and max ..thank you

Comment: Nice! I will post is an answer for further reference.

Answer (score 1):

Group by Absence_ID, work type, leave type, selecting min start date and max end date.