# mysql start and end date for contiguous dates in multiple rows

Tags: mysql, gaps-and-islands

My schedule table

| ID | UserID | Date | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2021-01-03 | vacation |
| 2 | 1 | 2021-01-04 | vacation |
| 3 | 1 | 2021-01-05 | present |
| 4 | 2 | 2021-01-01 | present |
| 5 | 2 | 2021-01-02 | vacation |
| 6 | 2 | 2021-01-03 | vacation |
| 6 | 2 | 2021-01-04 | vacation |
| 6 | 2 | 2021-01-05 | present |
| 7 | 2 | 2021-01-07 | vacation |

I tried doing a bit of logic using query from this example
[find start and stop date for contiguous dates in multiple rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24289958/find-start-and-stop-date-for-contiguous-dates-in-multiple-rows#)

But I need to get output like this.

| UserID | Start | End | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-01-03 | 2021-01-04 | vacation |
| 2 | 2021-01-02 | 2021-01-04 | vacation |
| 2 | 2021-01-07 | 2021-01-07 | vacation |

Comment: where does the ID in your desired results come from?

Comment: you are only looking for status='vacation'?

Comment: do show what you tried, please

Comment: @ysth 
The desired result don't need any id, sorry for that
It just needs userID, startDate, endDate, status

Comment: what does `select version();` show?

Comment: and again, please show what you tried; it will reveal important information about what you are trying to accomplish that just the text you provide does not.